# sqlserver records need to come horizontly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table structure below,

**Table Name: Customer**

```
Cust_id    Cust_Name
------------------------   
    101        John
    102        Peter
```

**Table Name: Loan_Details**

```
    Id   LoanName         Cust_Id    Amt
  -----------------------------------------
    1    PersonalLoan    101        2L 
    2    PersonalLoan    101        3L
    3    HomeLoan        101        10L
```

**Table Name: Product**

```
    Id    Cust_Id     ProductName    Cost
   -----------------------------------------
    1     101        Product1        1000 
    2     101        Product1        2000
    3     101        Product1        3000
```

I need result horizontly in below structure, is it possble?

```
Cust_Id Cust_Name   PersonalLoan    Amt   HomeLoan   Amt    ProductName   Cost
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
101     John        PersonalLoan    2L    HomeLoan   10L    Product1       1000
101     John        PersonalLoan    3L    NULL       NULL   Product1       2000
101     John        NULL            NULL  NULL       NULL   Product1       3000
```

Comment: Join the tables based on relationship among them,  and then select required fields

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle (pl/sql)? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Im using SQL Server

Comment: You are missing some links. example, why HomeLoan 10L is not populated in front of PersonalLoan 3L ?

Comment: You're missing a relationship between `Product` and `Loan_Details`

Comment: There is no relationship between Product and Loan_Details. Customer have many Loans and Customer have Many Products. thats it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query.

If you want to list "Peter" too, just change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` in the CusPrd subquery.

```
DECLARE @Customer TABLE (Cust_id VARCHAR(10),    Cust_Name VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @Customer
VALUES 
('101','John'),
('102','Peter')

DECLARE @Loan_Details TABLE  (Id INT, LoanName VARCHAR(20), Cust_Id VARCHAR(10),    Amt VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Loan_Details 
VALUES
(1,'PersonalLoan','101','2L'), 
(2,'PersonalLoan','101','3L'),
(3,'HomeLoan','101','10L')

DECLARE @Product TABLE (Id INT, Cust_Id VARCHAR(10), ProductName VARCHAR(20),   Cost INT)
INSERT INTO @Product
VALUES
(1,'101','Product1',1000),
(2,'101','Product1',2000),
(3,'101','Product1',3000)


;WITH Loan AS 
(
    SELECT *, 
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LoanName ORDER BY Id) 
    FROM @Loan_Details
),
CusPrd AS 
(
    SELECT 
        C.Cust_id, 
        C.Cust_Name,
        P.ProductName, 
        P.Cost, 
        P.Id, 
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.Cust_id ORDER BY P.Id)
    FROM 
        @Customer C 
        INNER JOIN  @Product P ON C.Cust_id = P.Cust_Id
)

SELECT  C.Cust_id, C.Cust_Name, PL.LoanName [PersonalLoan], PL.Amt, HL.LoanName [HomeLoan], HL.Amt, C.ProductName, C.Cost 
FROM 
    CusPrd C
    LEFT JOIN Loan PL ON PL.Cust_Id = C.Cust_id AND PL.LoanName ='PersonalLoan' AND C.RN = PL.RN
    LEFT JOIN Loan HL ON HL.Cust_Id = C.Cust_id AND HL.LoanName ='HomeLoan' AND PL.RN = HL.RN AND C.RN = PL.RN
```

Result:

```
Cust_id    Cust_Name            PersonalLoan         Amt        HomeLoan             Amt        ProductName          Cost
---------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------- -------------------- ---------- -------------------- -----------
101        John                 PersonalLoan         2L         HomeLoan             10L        Product1             1000
101        John                 PersonalLoan         3L         NULL                 NULL       Product1             2000
101        John                 NULL                 NULL       NULL                 NULL       Product1             3000
```

Comment: You're missing an Alias on `Cust_Id` on the second `Row_Number` function

Comment: @Cool_Br33ze thank you for the notice, I fixed it. In my language "i" and "I" different chars, that's why I did not get any error on my server.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from
(select c.Cust_id,Cust_Name,ld.LoanName as Loan,Amt,ProductName,Cost
from Customer c left join Product p on p.Cust_id=c.Cust_id
left join Loan_Details ld on ld.Cust_id = c.Cust_id) as MTable
PIVOT
(
SUM(Amt) for Loan in ([HomeLoan],[PersonalLoan])
) as PTable
```

Use this it will give you what you want the result is something like this

```
Cust_id     Cust_Name            ProductName          Cost        HomeLoan    PersonalLoan
----------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- ------------
101         John                 Product1             1000        10          5
101         John                 Product12            2000        10          5
101         John                 Product2             3000        10          5
102         Peter                NULL                 NULL        NULL        NULL
```

Comment: Where is PersonalLoan 3L ?? Please avoid answering just for sake of answering.